# What is the meaning of "|" in R

Tags: r, plm

I'm watching a video on YouTube about linear regression, one line of code is like this (function `pgmm` of package `plm`):

```
model1 = pgmm(democracy~lag(democracy)+lag(income)|lag(democracy, 2:99), DemocracyIncome25, index=c("country", "year"), model="twosteps", effect="twoways")
```

Just want to know what is the meaning of `|` here, and what does this operation really do.

Comment: Have a look at the Details section of the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/2.4-1/topics/pgmm

Comment: It means `or` for each element: `c(T,T,F) | c(T,F,T) == c(T,T.T)`

Comment: @danlooo this is inside a formula, where things are different (and... complicated)

Comment: @danlooo, normally yes, but this is inside a function for generalized method of moments

Comment: Ok. Inside a formula it usually indicates nested random factors e.g. `country|city`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the `|` represents the logical `OR` operator, but in the `pgmm` function the `|` sign is used to provide the instrumental variables that you want to use in your panel data GMM.

in your sample code `model1 = pgmm(democracy~lag(democracy)+lag(income)|lag(democracy, 2:99), DemocracyIncome25, index=c("country", "year"), model="twosteps", effect="twoways")`
you have the dependent variable democracy and independent variables as lag of democracy and lagged income. The variables after the `|` lag(democracy, 2:99), DemocracyIncome25 will act as instrumental variables.

Please refer to the page 17 of the plm documentation here [to the page 17 of the plm package documentation here](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-02-04/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf)

Comment: Wrong on one account: `5==3|4` is *also* `TRUE`, but not (obviously) because 5 is equal to 3 or 4. What is happening is that `3|4` is reverting to the logical interpretation of numbers: if a number is zero then it is false, otherwise it is true. With that, `5==3|4` reduces to `5==TRUE`, which, by the same logic reduces to `TRUE==TRUE`. The rest of your answer is fine, but please update or remove that first paragraph and I'll change my downvote.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your answer, hope it was not out of place.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for the updating the answer

Comment: Thanks! I think I grasp the outline. There's another question though. What is the mathematical form of this formula: democracy~lag(democracy)+lag(income)|lag(democracy, 2:99)? I'm still not very clear what a role the instrumental variable plays in this model.